# Why weights in accrod.net SimpleLinearRegression have no effect?

Tags: c#, prediction, accord.net

SimpleLinearRegression function in accord.net has a weights input to adjust weight of importance for each input-output pair. I use the following code to see how it affects the results.

```
        // Use Ordinary Least Squares to learn the regression
        OrdinaryLeastSquares oOls1 = new OrdinaryLeastSquares();
        OrdinaryLeastSquares oOls2 = new OrdinaryLeastSquares();

        // Use OLS to learn the simple linear regression
        SimpleLinearRegression oSimpleLinReg1 = oOls1.Learn(adInputs, adOutputs);
        SimpleLinearRegression oSimpleLinReg2 = oOls2.Learn(adInputs, adOutputs, adWeights);

        double dPrediction1 = oSimpleLinReg1.Transform(dTestInpData);
        double dPrediction1 = oSimpleLinReg2.Transform(dTestInpData);
```

No matter what I put in adWeights, everytime dPrediction1 and dPrediction2 are equal. Can anyone provide and example to show how adWeights affects prediction output? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This was a bug in the framework, sorry for any inconvenience this might have caused.